# Can I use DirectAccess with just Windows 10 Pro, not Enterprise?

Tags: windows

I have set up DirectAccess on a company server but only Windows Pro clients so am unable to connect. I think Microsoft should update Win 10 Pro to allow clients to connect. Is there a possible workaround or am I forced to upgrade all the clients to Windows Enterprise?

Aside.. I understand that you can fool Windows by using a generic Windows 10 Enterprise product key, which works but that will not activate.

The Prerequisites for Deploying DirectAccess that are imposed by Microsoft include, the need for one of the following client operating systems.
- Windows 10® Enterprise
- Windows 10® Enterprise 2015 Long Term Servicing Branch (LTSB)
- Windows® 8 and 8.1 Enterprise
- Windows® 7 Ultimate
- Windows® 7 Enterprise

Richard Hicks addresses the persistent rumour about Windows 10 Pro changing to now support DirectAccess - [here](https://directaccess.richardhicks.com/2015/12/14/directaccess-and-windows-10-professional/)

My query is two-fold.
1. Will Microsoft update Windows 10 Pro to work with DirectAccess in the future instead of imposing the requirement to upgrade to Windows 10 Enterprise.
2. Is there a smart technical way of bypassing this operating system restriction and allowing Windows 10 Pro to work somehow with DirectAccess, without being forced to upgrade to the Enterprise version.

How-To Geek have a good article [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/250503/how-to-upgrade-to-windows-10-enterprise-without-reinstalling-windows/)
That explains how to upgrade to Windows 10 Enterprise for free - just without being able to activate.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

This feature is limited to use in the Enterprise-targeted Windows version, which Pro is not.